# How to override Rails' select form helper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to override Rails' form select helper like this:

```
def select(method, choices, options = {}, html_options = {})
  html_options.reverse_merge!(:disabled => true)
  super(method, choices, options = {}, html_options = {})
end
```

The goal is to `disable` all select tags.

Unfortunately, it isn't working at all. The select boxes do not get disabled at all and no error is thrown either. I have already verified that the method gets called properly in the form, so that can't be the problem.

Can anybody tell me what I am missing here?

Thanks for any pointers.

Comment: Sorry, didn't get the point what actually not working?

Comment: Have you tried `:disabled => "disabled"`?

Comment: I just did, works out the same...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're resetting the options options when you send it to super.

```
def select(method, choices, options = {}, html_options = {})
  html_options.reverse_merge!(:disabled => true)

  # Don't do this!  By doing this you're *always* sending empty objects for
  # options and html_options to super.
  #super(method, choices, options = {}, html_options = {})

  # Do this!
  super(method, choices, options, html_options)
end
```